# Depending dropdown data showing Faild assertion error

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I need to display list of **Lab** name in the dropdown list and when I click Lab name it need to go to respective **Test** of that Lab. I tried with different possible way to achieve this, following approach seems to understandable for me but its showing some kind of Error

```
    The following assertion was thrown building MyHomePage(dirty, state: _MyHomePageState#ec203):
A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
Failed assertion: line 378 pos 10: 'data != null'
```

//CALLING LAB API HERE

```
 List allLabList;
  String _myLab;

  String allLabInfoUrl = 'http://myurldjhjhfsf';
  Future<String> _getLabList() async {
    await http.post(allLabInfoUrl,  body: {

    }).then((response) {
      var data = json.decode(response.body);

//      print(data);
      setState(() {
        allLabList = data['Partner'];
      });
    });
  }

  // Get TEST information by API
  List testList;
  String _myTest;

  String allTestInfoUrl ='http://putmyurlhere';
  Future<String> _getTestList() async {
    await http.post(allTestInfoUrl,  body: {

      "TestId": _myLab,
    }).then((response) {
      var data = json.decode(response.body);

      setState(() {
        testList = data['Data'];
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Initialize your string to an empty string(var abc = ''). If you don't, it's null, which causes the issue. Also you don't need async/await as you are using "then" syntax.

Comment: I believe that because my API doesn't provide data to my dropdown. I'm also confused when I'm passing parameters as I didn't use `Model` class to serialize the data. Can You please help me with that by looking the code here: [ https://gist.github.com/Roy-Tuhin/29256a888fd016940faf07ae470d1534 ]

Comment: I also try My approach here I'm, getting my API response in my console but when I try to display in dropdown its showing  error like `List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<DropdownMenuItem<Partner>>?'   `[ https://gist.github.com/Roy-Tuhin/b814a66083b2198dbb0189f222fbba56 ]

Comment: My approach [ https://gist.github.com/Roy-Tuhin/b814a66083b2198dbb0189f222fbba56 ] working now...but not for multilevel dropdown.